# How do I fix a layout conflict between navigationTitle and toolbar in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want my navigationBar to look like this:
[image]

In a NavigationView, I am using the following code to add both a title and navigationBarItems:

```
 .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
 .navigationTitle("Questions")
 .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Help") {showingAbout.toggle()}
                        NavigationLink(destination:ImportView()){
                            Text("Import")
                        }
                    }
                    
                })
```

It looks the way I want it, but when I run the code I always get issues with layout constraints:

> 2021-10-28 20:35:16.370287+0200 metrig[50881:1781380] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
> Try this:
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
> (
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001646e90 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13ed237b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x13ed20bf0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001647c00 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x13ed237b0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600000c7bc60'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001647cf0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x13ed20bf0]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600000c7bb80'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000016451d0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600000c7bb80'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13ed1f5a0.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000164b390 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x13ed1f5a0.width == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001645090 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-UILayoutGuide:0x600000c7bc60'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x13ed1f5a0 )>"
> )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001646e90 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x13ed237b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x13ed20bf0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

No matter what I try, moving them around, using Item instead of ItemGroup... I can’t seem to get both a title and buttons in the toolbar without layout conflict.

What’s the problem?

Comment: There isn't one. SwiftUI will throw those warnings a lot. So long as things are working, you can ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI isn't perfect and it could just be 'log noise' as discussed in this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461). However, whenever I received this issue on layout constraints, adding `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` (or equivalent for older versions of SwiftUI) to the `NavigationView` seemed to get rid of them.